# How do you loop over an array of objects and get a key from each? (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects.  I need to loop over the array, access the same key in each object, and compare the string properties to another array, to see if the string shares any words with it.  If it does: do something.

I can successfully compare the array I have with a hardcoded string, using the Lodash _.difference method.  But I'm confused as to how to get the string from the key of each object using a loop.  I tried forEach, but I can't seem to get the keys of each element.

What is the best way to go about achieving this?

Thanks so much.

## Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NewsApiService } from '../service/news-api.service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { MapComponent } from '../map/map.component';

import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  private bbcJSON: any;
  private alJazeeraJSON: any;
  private bingWorldJSON: any;
  private bingPoliticsJSON: any;




  share(event) {
      this.bbcJSON.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.description);
      })
}
```

Error in console:  inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: please add the raw data, the wanted result and what you have tried. you may have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: some sample code

Comment: if you are confused...how do you think we feel trying to match things we can't see the structure of ? Would be a good time to thoroughly read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of objects, an array of strings and you're using underscore.js.

Here's the example I ran through to interpret your question. I assumed that you're looking for the intersection on the key a:

```
var arObj = [ { a: "a", b: "b" }, { a: "c", b: "d" } ];
var compareArray = [ "c", "d" ];

var sharedWords = _.intersection(_.pluck(arObj, "a"), compareArray);
```

To answer your title question - if you're using underscore you can just do _.pluck(array_of_objects, *key*) to get an array of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const ref = ["foo", "baz"];

const arr = [
  { name: "foo" },
  { name: "bar" },
  { name: "baz" }
];

for (const obj of arr) {
  if (ref.includes(obj.name)) {
    console.log(`Do something with ${obj.name}...`);
  }
}
```